# How to batch clear animation layer data of all the selected objects in the scene?

Tags: python, outliner

I have imported bunch of .glb objects in the blender file. Every object has animation layer and NLA strip. I want to clear that layer of all the objects at once with the script.

**How it works for single object:**
First select object and expand it in outliner. Then select its animation layer. Right click and clear animation data. This is the command. bpy.ops.outliner.animdata_operation(type='CLEAR_ANIMDATA')

I want the perform above operation for all the selected objects all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the trick. Just type 'animation' in search bar. Then select all the highlighted layers. Right click and clear animation data.